# flood of unresolved external symbol errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, directx, directx-11

I come here since I have a problem with my project for a good while now...

It's a video game project running with DirectX 11, under Visual studio express Windows app.

After having a problem with a function, I wanted ti give a try to the release version... However, after returning to the Debug version, something horrible happens...

I'm flooded by unresolved external symbol errors everytimes I try to compilate.
Nothing I tried to do succeed, like recompiling, cleaning, etc... I checked in the configurations, and nothing seems to have changed (at least the configurations I know, I'm still not an expert, so...)

I checked the directories, the libraries, but everything in this point seems ok... Can you help me please?

So you can get an idea of my problem, here are my errors...

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol **_Platform_CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\main.obj   1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\Texture.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\Element.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\GameWindow.obj 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\LevelEditor.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsDeleteString@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl __abi_details::__abi_delete_String(class Platform::String ^)" (?__abi_delete_String@__abi_details@@YAXP$AAVString@Platform@@@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\Element.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsDeleteString@4    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\GameWindow.obj 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsDeleteString@4    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\LevelEditor.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsDeleteString@4    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsDeleteString@4.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsDuplicateString@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl Platform::Details::DuplicateString(struct HSTRING** *,struct HSTRING__ * *)" (?DuplicateString@Details@Platform@@YAXPAUHSTRING__@@PAPAU3@@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\Element.obj    1
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol **_Platform_WindowsDuplicateString@8 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\GameWindow.obj 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsDuplicateString@8 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\LevelEditor.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsDuplicateString@8 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsDuplicateString@8.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoTaskMemAlloc@4 referenced in function "protected: static class Platform::String ^ * __cdecl Platform::WriteOnlyArray::AllocateAndZeroInitialize(unsigned int)" (?AllocateAndZeroInitialize@?$WriteOnlyArray@P$AAVString@Platform@@$00@Platform@@KAPAP$AAVString@2@I@Z) Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\Element.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoTaskMemAlloc@4 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\GameWindow.obj 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoTaskMemAlloc@4 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__CoTaskMemAlloc@4.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoTaskMemFree@4 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Platform::Details::array_helper::DestructElementsAndFree(class Platform::String ^ *,unsigned int)" (?DestructElementsAndFree@?$array_helper@P$AAVString@Platform@@$0A@@Details@Platform@@SAXPAP$AAVString@3@I@Z) Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\Element.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoTaskMemFree@4  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\GameWindow.obj 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_CoTaskMemFree@4  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__CoTaskMemFree@4.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsGetStringRawBuffer@8 referenced in function "public: wchar_t const * __cdecl Platform::String::Data(void)" (?Data@String@Platform@@Q$AAAPB_WXZ)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\GameWindow.obj 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsGetStringRawBuffer@8  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\LevelEditor.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsGetStringRawBuffer@8  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsGetStringRawBuffer@8.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsGetStringLen@4 referenced in function "public: unsigned int __cdecl Platform::String::Length(void)" (?Length@String@Platform@@Q$AAAIXZ)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\LevelEditor.obj    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsGetStringLen@4    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsGetStringLen@4.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___Platform_WindowsCreateStringReference@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl Platform::Details::CreateStringReference(wchar_t const *,unsigned int,struct __Platform_Details_HSTRING_HEADER *,struct HSTRING** * *)" (?CreateStringReference@Details@Platform@@YAXPB_WIPAU__Platform_Details_HSTRING_HEADER@@PAPAUHSTRING__@@@Z) Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\LevelEditor.obj    1
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol **_Platform_WindowsCreateStringReference@16  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsCreateStringReference@16.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__ReadFile@20 referenced in function "long __cdecl LoadTextureDataFromFile(wchar_t const *,class std::unique_ptr > &,struct DirectX::DDS_HEADER * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadTextureDataFromFile@@YAJPB_WAAV?$unique_ptr@$$BY0A@EU?$default_delete@$$BY0A@E@std@@@std@@PAPAUDDS_HEADER@DirectX@@PAPAEPAI@Z) Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\DirectXTK.lib(DDSTextureLoader.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateFile2@20 referenced in function "long __cdecl LoadTextureDataFromFile(wchar_t const *,class std::unique_ptr > &,struct DirectX::DDS_HEADER * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadTextureDataFromFile@@YAJPB_WAAV?$unique_ptr@$$BY0A@EU?$default_delete@$$BY0A@E@std@@@std@@PAPAUDDS_HEADER@DirectX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\DirectXTK.lib(DDSTextureLoader.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CloseHandle@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall DirectX::handle_closer::operator()(void *)" (??Rhandle_closer@DirectX@@QAEXPAX@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\DirectXTK.lib(DDSTextureLoader.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__CloseHandle@4 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__GetLastError@0 referenced in function "long __cdecl LoadTextureDataFromFile(wchar_t const *,class std::unique_ptr > &,struct DirectX::DDS_HEADER * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadTextureDataFromFile@@YAJPB_WAAV?$unique_ptr@$$BY0A@EU?$default_delete@$$BY0A@E@std@@@std@@PAPAUDDS_HEADER@DirectX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\DirectXTK.lib(DDSTextureLoader.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__GetLastError@0    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*pdblkup*.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__GetFileInformationByHandleEx@16 referenced in function "long __cdecl LoadTextureDataFromFile(wchar_t const *,class std::unique_ptr > &,struct DirectX::DDS_HEADER * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadTextureDataFromFile@@YAJPB_WAAV?$unique_ptr@$$BY0A@EU?$default_delete@$$BY0A@E@std@@@std@@PAPAUDDS_HEADER@DirectX@@PAPAEPAI@Z) Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\DirectXTK.lib(DDSTextureLoader.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__WideCharToMultiByte@32 referenced in function "long __cdecl DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx(struct ID3D11Device *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int,enum D3D11_USAGE,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,bool,struct ID3D11Resource * *,struct ID3D11ShaderResourceView * *,enum DirectX::DDS_ALPHA_MODE *)" (?CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx@DirectX@@YAJPAUID3D11Device@@PAUID3D11DeviceContext@@PB_WIW4D3D11_USAGE@@III_NPAPAUID3D11Resource@@PAPAUID3D11ShaderResourceView@@PAW4DDS_ALPHA_MODE@1@@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\DirectXTK.lib(DDSTextureLoader.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__WideCharToMultiByte@32    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*error*.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__DecodePointer@4 referenced in function "bool __cdecl Microsoft::WRL::Details::TerminateMap(class Microsoft::WRL::Details::ModuleBase *,wchar_t const *,bool)" (?TerminateMap@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YA_NPAVModuleBase@123@PB_W_N@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__ReleaseSRWLockExclusive@4 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::SRWLockExclusiveTraits::Unlock(struct _RTL_SRWLOCK *)" (?Unlock@SRWLockExclusiveTraits@HandleTraits@Wrappers@WRL@Microsoft@@SAXPAU_RTL_SRWLOCK@@@Z) Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__AcquireSRWLockExclusive@4 referenced in function "public: static class Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::Details::SyncLockT __cdecl Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::SRWLock::LockExclusive(struct _RTL_SRWLOCK *)" (?LockExclusive@SRWLock@Wrappers@WRL@Microsoft@@SA?AV?$SyncLockT@USRWLockExclusiveTraits@HandleTraits@Wrappers@WRL@Microsoft@@@Details@234@PAU_RTL_SRWLOCK@@@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SetRestrictedErrorInfo@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl Platform::Details::ReportUnhandledError(class Platform::Exception ^)" (?ReportUnhandledError@Details@Platform@@YAXP$AAVException@2@@Z)    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _RoFailFastWithErrorContext@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl Platform::Details::ReportUnhandledError(class Platform::Exception ^)" (?ReportUnhandledError@Details@Platform@@YAXP$AAVException@2@@Z)    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _RoReportUnhandledError@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl Platform::Details::ReportUnhandledError(class Platform::Exception ^)" (?ReportUnhandledError@Details@Platform@@YAXP$AAVException@2@@Z)    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WindowsCreateString@12 referenced in function "long __stdcall __winRT::__windowsCreateString(wchar_t const *,int,struct HSTRING** * *)" (?**windowsCreateString@__winRT@@YGJPB_WHPAPAUHSTRING**@@@Z)    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(compiler.obj)    1
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WindowsCreateString@12  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(climain.obj) 1
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(**Platform__CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WindowsDeleteString@4   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsDeleteString@4.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WindowsDeleteString@4   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(climain.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WindowsDuplicateString@8    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsDuplicateString@8.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WindowsDuplicateString@8    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(climain.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _CoTaskMemAlloc@4    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__CoTaskMemAlloc@4.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _CoTaskMemFree@4 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__CoTaskMemFree@4.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WindowsGetStringRawBuffer@8 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsGetStringRawBuffer@8.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WindowsGetStringLen@4   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsGetStringLen@4.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WindowsCreateStringReference@16 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(__Platform__WindowsCreateStringReference@16.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__EnterCriticalSection@4 referenced in function __Init_thread_lock  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__LeaveCriticalSection@4 referenced in function __Init_thread_unlock    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__InitializeCriticalSectionEx@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics(void)" (?__scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics@@YAHXZ)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__DeleteCriticalSection@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl __scrt_uninitialize_thread_safe_statics(void)" (?__scrt_uninitialize_thread_safe_statics@@YAXXZ) Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__InitializeConditionVariable@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics(void)" (?__scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics@@YAHXZ)    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__WakeAllConditionVariable@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics(void)" (?__scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics@@YAHXZ)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__SleepConditionVariableCS@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics(void)" (?__scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics@@YAHXZ)  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetEvent@4 referenced in function __Init_thread_notify    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__ResetEvent@4 referenced in function __Init_thread_notify  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__WaitForSingleObjectEx@12 referenced in function __Init_thread_wait    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _SleepConditionVariableCS@12 Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WakeAllConditionVariable@4  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(thread_safe_statics.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__IsDebuggerPresent@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl failwithmessage(void *,int,int,char const *)" (?failwithmessage@@YAXPAXHHPBD@Z)  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*error*.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__RaiseException@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl DebuggerProbe(unsigned long)" (?DebuggerProbe@@YAHK@Z)  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*error*.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__MultiByteToWideChar@24 referenced in function "void __cdecl failwithmessage(void *,int,int,char const *)" (?failwithmessage@@YAXPAXHHPBD@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*error*.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _IsProcessorFeaturePresent@4 referenced in function ___isa_available_init    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(_cpu_disp_.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__RoInitialize@4 referenced in function ___scrt_initialize_winrt    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(utility_app.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__QueryPerformanceCounter@4 referenced in function ___security_init_cookie  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_support.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__GetCurrentProcessId@0 referenced in function ___security_init_cookie  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_support.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0 referenced in function ___security_init_cookie   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_support.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime@4 referenced in function ___security_init_cookie  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_support.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__InitializeSListHead@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl __scrt_initialize_type_info(void)" (?__scrt_initialize_type_info@@YAXXZ)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(tncleanup.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__HeapAlloc@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl _RTC_GetSrcLine(unsigned char *,wchar_t *,unsigned long,int *,wchar_t *,unsigned long)" (?_RTC_GetSrcLine@@YAHPAEPA_WKPAH1K@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*pdblkup*.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__HeapFree@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl _RTC_GetSrcLine(unsigned char *,wchar_t *,unsigned long,int *,wchar_t *,unsigned long)" (?_RTC_GetSrcLine@@YAHPAEPA_WKPAH1K@Z)    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*pdblkup*.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__GetProcessHeap@0 referenced in function "int __cdecl _RTC_GetSrcLine(unsigned char *,wchar_t *,unsigned long,int *,wchar_t *,unsigned long)" (?_RTC_GetSrcLine@@YAHPAEPA_WKPAH1K@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*pdblkup*.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__VirtualQuery@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl _RTC_GetSrcLine(unsigned char *,wchar_t *,unsigned long,int *,wchar_t *,unsigned long)" (?_RTC_GetSrcLine@@YAHPAEPA_WKPAH1K@Z)    Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*pdblkup*.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__FreeLibrary@4 referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE** * **cdecl GetPdbDllFromInstallPath(void)" (?GetPdbDllFromInstallPath@@YAPAUHINSTANCE**@@XZ)  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*pdblkup*.obj) 1
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol **imp__GetProcAddress@8 referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE** * **cdecl GetPdbDllFromInstallPath(void)" (?GetPdbDllFromInstallPath@@YAPAUHINSTANCE**@@XZ)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\MSVCRTD.lib(*pdblkup*.obj) 1
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler@8 referenced in function "public: long __stdcall __abi_FTMWeakRefData::__abi_QueryInterface(class Platform::Guid &,void * *)" (?__abi_QueryInterface@__abi_FTMWeakRefData@@QAGJAAVGuid@Platform@@PAPAX@Z)   Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(climain.obj) 1
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CoTaskMemAlloc@4 referenced in function "protected: static class Platform::String ^ * __cdecl Platform::WriteOnlyArray::AllocateAndZeroInitialize(unsigned int)" (?AllocateAndZeroInitialize@?$WriteOnlyArray@P$AAVString@Platform@@$00@Platform@@KAPAP$AAVString@2@I@Z)  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(climain.obj) 1
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CoTaskMemFree@4 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Platform::Details::array_helper::DestructElementsAndFree(class Platform::String ^ *,unsigned int)" (?DestructElementsAndFree@?$array_helper@P$AAVString@Platform@@$0A@@Details@Platform@@SAXPAP$AAVString@3@I@Z)  Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Game level editor\vccorlibd.lib(climain.obj) 1
>   Error   LNK1120 60 unresolved externals Game level editor   C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Game level editor\Debug\Game level editor\Game level editor.exe    1

Comment: An unresolved symbol error usually means you need either link object or libraries that have symbol resolved or add the source file to your project.

Comment: BTW, a good idea is to type the error code, LNK2019, into your internet search engine.  You can narrow the search by including other keywords like "directx" or "c++".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that it worked before, and without any major change, suddenly started to produce the errors... I tried to check on the net for the libs I should add manually, but some of the functions aren't even supposed to have any .lib to get used (example: WindowsDeleteString)
So even if I link everything I can, some of the errors will still remain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that an option disappeared from the properties (Properties > Linker > Command line). After comparing with a just created project, I noticed that "WindowsApp.lib"  has disappeared... I added it as an additional option and it worked again.

Well, still thank you for trying to help me. :3